# UIAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler. Odd functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am making an alert that has a couple of text fields, this will be saved on a server once save is hit. I managed to get it to function but found something odd that I didn't understand. I'm not sure how to explain it in words so I will post the code in question.

```
var enteredName: UITextField!

let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    println(self.enteredName.text)
}
myAlert.addAction(saveAction)
myAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
    textField.placeholder = "Name"
    self.enteredName = textField
}
self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now, the above code works, and I have no problems with it, however, I had a very similar block of code originally that did not work. The above code snippet will display an alert with a text field, after typing in something and hitting save it will print what you typed. The below code was supposed to do that but printed blank lines, I assume empty strings.

```
var enteredName: String!

let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    println(self.enteredName)
}
myAlert.addAction(saveAction)
myAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
    textField.placeholder = "Name"
    self.enteredName = textField.text
}
self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As you can see, not much has been changed, and to me, both code blocks look like they should run. The differences: In the code snippet that did not work

1. The variable is a String instead of a UITextField
2. The variable is being saved to textField.text instead of textField
3. The alert is printing self.enteredName instead of self.enteredName.text

So my question is this, why did the bottom text block not work properly while the top block did?

Comment: While I know it is not required, I would appreciate comments on why you are down voting so I am able to either edit it to better conform, or understand what I did wrong so my next question will be more on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addTextFieldConfigurationHandler` method is called before the user has an opportunity to to type anything and press save (and therefore, before the code you put in the `saveAction` is ever executed).

The only time in the bottom example you *ever* assign anything to your `enteredName` string is when you're adding the text field configuration handler.  The text field configuration handler is never called at any point after the user sees the text field (so never after the user has an opportunity to type in the text field).

And the string variable can't just magically get the value from the text field.

Comment: That makes sense, but then how does the top example work? How is the enteredName variable getting _its_ data to then use later?

Comment: The top example makes `self.enteredName` point to the same object as the `textField`.  `UITextField` is a reference type.  So when the `.text` property changes, both variables see it.  All the variable is is just a pointer to a memory location that has a `UITextField` there, and you made them both point to the same memory location.